# Auth0 in NextJS: API resolved without sending a response

Tags: javascript, next.js, auth0

I used the following article from Auth0 to set-up user login in my NextJS app: https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/nextjs/01-login#configure-auth0. These are the basic steps:

1. Install `@auth0/nextjs-auth0`
2. Wrap my root component in `_app.tsx` with a `<UserProvider>` component.
3. Create an `auth` folder in `pages/api` with a file called `[...auth0].js` that exports `handleAuth` from `@auth0/nextjs-auth0`.
4. Create `.env` file with the proper configuration.

However, when I try to sign in by clicking the following link: `<a href="/api/auth/login">Login</a>`, nothing is happening - there is just loading - and I am seeing the following server message: `API resolved without sending a response for /api/auth/login, this may result in stalled requests`. I triple checked that I followed everything from the article properly and I can't figure out why it's not working. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Auth0 doesn't support app directory of Next.js yet.

https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/nextjs/01-login

The app directory introduced with Next.js 13 is currently in beta, and Vercel does not recommend using it in production. As such, this SDK does not support it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Auth0 currently is not supporting new app directory. You can use NextAuth instead.

I found one tutorial where you can integrate django with nextjs 13 application using NextAuth as an authentication.

https://mahieyin-rahmun.medium.com/how-to-configure-social-authentication-in-a-next-js-next-auth-django-rest-framework-application-cb4c82be137